# C# code calling C++/CLI class method - new instance still has old instance values

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, c++-cli, marshalling, destructor

I am a newbie in terms of working with both C# and C++/CLI code together. In my C# code, I am creating a new instance of a class FooClass and running a method FooClass:ParseCmdArgs, which takes in a System::String, converts to a std::string, and then pushes to a vector "bars" variable. I then print out the "bars" content at the end of ParseCmdArgs function. But I am getting some unexpected output described below.

**C# Code - WPF Application**

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CLRClass.FooClass foo = new CLRClass.FooClass();

    List<string> args = new List<string>();
    args.Add("1st Run - 1");
    args.Add("1st Run - 2");
    args.Add("1st Run - 3");
    args.Add("1st Run - 4");
    args.Add("1st Run - 5");

    foo.ParseCmdArgs(args.Count, args.ToArray());

    args.Clear();
    args.Add("2nd Run - 1");
    args.Add("2nd Run - 2");
    args.Add("2nd Run - 3");
    args.Add("2nd Run - 4");
    args.Add("2nd Run - 5");

    foo = new CLRClass.FooClass();
    foo.ParseCmdArgs(args.Count, args.ToArray());
}
```

**CLRClass.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;

namespace CLRClass {

  public ref class FooClass
  {
  public:
    void ParseCmdArgs(int, array<System::String^>^);
  };
}
```

**CLRClass.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "CLRClass.h"

using namespace CLRClass;
using namespace std;

vector<string> bars;

void FooClass::ParseCmdArgs(int argc, array<System::String^> ^argvManaged) {
  string *argv;
  argv = new string[argc];

  for (int j = 0; j < argc; j++) {
    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    std::string standardString = context.marshal_as<std::string>(argvManaged[j]);

    argv[j] = standardString;

    bars.push_back(argv[j]);
  }

  cout << "print bars" << endl;
  cout << "-----------" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < bars.size(); i++) {
    cout << bars[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

**The output is:**

```
print bars
-----------
1st Run - 1
1st Run - 2
1st Run - 3
1st Run - 4
1st Run - 5
print bars
-----------
1st Run - 1
1st Run - 2
1st Run - 3
1st Run - 4
1st Run - 5
2nd Run - 1
2nd Run - 2
2nd Run - 3
2nd Run - 4
2nd Run - 5
```

I have a few queries if you could assist me here:

1) I did not expect the first instance of the FooClass assigned to "foo" to still keep the content of the "bars" variable (in the C++/CLI code). As we can see from the output, after assigning a new instance of FooClass to "foo", the old content from the "1st Run" is stored in the "new" FooClass instance's "bars" variable. 
1a) Could anyone see why this is happening?
1b) Do I need to setup a destructor for FooClass?

2) What would be the best way for me to call the ParseCmdArgs() function with one instance of FooClass? I suppose creating a new instance of FooClass is not ideal (which is not working anyways, see 1). Do I need to do a bars.clear() each time ParseCmdArgs is finished??

3) Is the way I am marshaling / converting the System::String to a std::string correct?

4) e.g. Is there any concern for memory leaks in my current implementation of C# managed code calling the unmanaged C++/CLI class and the use of marshaling?

Thank you advance for your help, and let me know if you need further details or clarifications.

Best Regards

Comment: The *bars* variable is an Evil Global Variable.  Intent is very unclear but you should put *static* in front of the ParseCmdArgs() function to match that.  And call it from your C# code with CLRClass.ParseCmdArgs(), now it is obvious that it modifies global state.

Comment: Thanks for assisting in the fight against evil (global variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `vector<string> bars;` a local variable of your function. Or at least an instance field of your class.

Right now it's a global variable that will keep it's value as long as you have the DLL loaded into your AppDomain (simply put, for the whole duration of your program).

This has nothing to do with the CLR or managed code. The same would happen if you called your C++ code from a C++ executable.